# Как правильно сокращать в названии церкви "святой", если их двое и более?

Tags: условные-сокращения

> Церковь святых Сильвестра и Мартина, Рим.

Мне необходимо сокращение слова "святых", потому что идёт вереница названий:

> ...Рассматривая ранние христианские церкви – Св. Пуденцианы, Св.
>   Сильвестра и Мартина на горе *(не надо горы! Церковь святых Сильвестра
>   и Мартина /San Silvestro e san Martino ai Monti)*, Св. Петра в оковах,
>   Св. Клименте, мы обнаруживаем устройство римских домов I века, которые
>   и составляли тогда эти городские кварталы.

Курсивное - это мой вопль к автору.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Святые — свв.

Весь перечень сокращений в церковном календаре здесь: http://www.molitvoslov.by/biblioteka/sokrashhennyie-oboznacheniya